# how to pass variable from nodejs to jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

i want to pass the variable from nodejs to jquery.

my nodejs:

```
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  let IndexPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public/index.html");
  let paramJquery = "testfromNod";
  response.sendFile(IndexPath);
});
```

my html:

```
   <div id="log"></div>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/client.js"></script>
```

and the last, my client.js

```
var $log = $( "#log" ),
  str = paramJquery,
  html = $.parseHTML( str ); 
 
$log.append( html );
```

Comment: The general answer is the same, no matter which server side language you use: Either have the client JavaScript code make an Ajax request to fetch the data or have the server code inject the variable into the HTML/script when the page is requested.

Comment: Thanks you, could you show me concretly please